# Error in migration when deploying ruby on rails application to DigitaOcean using DeployBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, digital-ocean

I followed the [Deploy Ruby on Rails to DigitalOcean](http://deploybot.com/guides/deploy-ruby-on-rails-to-digitalocean) Guide with success until I did an actual deploy. My *Post-launch commands* are as follows:

```
RAILS_ENV=production
rvm install
gem install bundle
bundle install --deployment
bundle exec rake db:setup
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

The deployment goes through the bundle install but when it comes to executing `rake db:setup` I get an error

> ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured. Available: ["production"]

But I thought `RAILS_ENV=production` would tell `db:setup` to use the `production` database but not the `development`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

login into the server edit `~/.bashrc` file and add it at the botton of the file:

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

then reboot the server, if it won't help check your database.yml file to see if you have `production` section configured correctly.

Comment: I checked my database.yml and DeployBot is actually creating this file and it contains only a production section.

shouldn't the top command in my post-launch commands set the RAILS_ENV?

Comment: No it won't stay forever because if you use `deploy` command new session is opened without this `ENV` value, you should have this value under ENV all the time and to make sure thats happen you should add what i wrote.

Comment: Thanks @matanco ... I will try deploying again later ... now I getting the following error when installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions.. not sure why.

`Cannot allocate memory - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151101-3776-p8pzyc.rb extconf.rb 2>&1`

Comment: what is the amount of RAM in your droplet?

Comment: 512mb -- I did `watch -n 5 free -m` and it says I have 67 free

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93923/discussion-between-matanco-and-bjorgvin).

Comment: increasing it to 1GB... haven't had a problem with memory until now; why is that?